# Recursive function returns only one value correctly

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree

So I am working on a JavaScript project for school. It uses a recursive function to create a tree of all the nodes within an article element on a web-page. The actual article element uses the makeBranches function to calculate how many of each type of node exists. It keeps count of element nodes, text nodes, whitespace nodes, and total nodes, and lists these in one of the paragraphs. However, all of the counts are one below what they should be, except for element nodes.

Edit: Here is the reproducible example. The numbers on the page are given in the second paragraph under the first h1 and h2 headings. I added the CSS code to highlight the numbers in red. The makeBranches function should return 238 total nodes, 98 element nodes, 140 text nodes, and 57 whitespace nodes. But all of the counts except for the element nodes are one short of what they should be.

```js
"use strict";

/* the global variables used to store the totals of each type of node; total nodes, element nodes, text nodes, and whitespace nodes*/
var nodeCount = 0;
var elemCount = 0;
var textCount = 0;
var wsCount = 0;

// runs the makeTree function upon page loading
window.onload = makeTree;

function makeTree() {

  

  var nodeList = document.createElement("ol");
  
  // creates variable "sourceArticle" as a reference to the article element with the id "main"
  var sourceArticle = document.querySelector("#main article");

  // calls the "makeBranches" function with "sourceArticle" and "nodeList" as parameters
  makeBranches(sourceArticle, nodeList);

  // outputs the totals of the nodes after calling the "makeBranches" function
  document.getElementById("totalNodes").innerHTML = nodeCount;
  document.getElementById("elemNodes").innerHTML = elemCount;
  document.getElementById("textNodes").innerHTML = textCount;
  document.getElementById("wsNodes").innerHTML = wsCount;


}

// this recursive function is supposed to tally the totals of the nodes
function makeBranches(treeNode, nestedList) {

  // increments "nodeCount"
  nodeCount++;

  
  // checks to see if the current node is a node of type 1 (element)
  if (treeNode.nodeType === 1) {
    // if true, increments "elemCount"
    elemCount++;

    
  }
  //checks to see if the current node is a node of type 3 (text node)
  if (treeNode.nodeType === 3) {
    // if true, increments "textCount"
    textCount++;

    // extracts the text string from the current node
    var textString = treeNode.nodeValue;

    // checks to see if the text string is whitespace or not
    if (isWhiteSpaceNode(textString) === true) {
      // if true, increments "wsCount"
      wsCount++;

      
    }
    

  }
  // checks to see if there are any remaining nodes
  if (treeNode.childNodes.length > 0) {
    var newList = document.createElement("ol");
    
    // recursion loop; calls this function again for every node remaining
    for (var n = treeNode.firstChild; n !== null; n = n.nextSibling) {
      // calls this function again with the parameters "n" and "newList"
      makeBranches(n, newList);
    }
  }

}
// this function checks to see if the given parameter is whitespace or not
function isWhiteSpaceNode(tString) {
  return !(/[^\t\n\r ]/.test(tString));
}
```

```css
span {
color: red}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!--
   New Perspectives on HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript 6th Edition
   Tutorial 12
   Case Problem 3
   Node Tree Map
   Author: Matthew Wheeler
   Date: 6-27-2022
   Filename: js_nodes.html
-->

  <title>JSWorks Node Tree</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <link href="js_base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="js_layout.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="js_tree.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="js_tree.js" async></script>

</head>

<body>

  <section id="page">
    <header>
      Customized Web Tools and Tutorials
      <img src="js_logo.png" alt="JSWorks" />
      <div>
        <label for="sBox">Search Topic</label>
        <input type="search" id="sBox" name="sBox" />
      </div>
    </header>
    <nav class="horizontal">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Apps</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sample Code</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">White Papers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Browser Charts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reference</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <section id="main">
      <article id="topArticle" class="aClass">
        <h1>Working with Nodes</h1>

        <h2>Understanding the Node Tree</h2>

        <p>JavaScript organizes an HTML document in a tree structure known as a <dfn>node tree</dfn>. Each HTML element, comment, and text string is stored within the tree as a separate node.
        </p>

        <p>The box on the right shows the node tree for this article. Note that line returns and blank spaces between element tags are counted as text nodes and appear in the node tree as white space nodes. In this article there are
          <span id="totalNodes"></span> total nodes, comprised of
          <span id="elemNodes"></span> element nodes, and
          <span id="textNodes"></span> text nodes (containing
          <span id="wsNodes"></span> white space nodes).
        </p>

        <h2>The Familial Relationship of Nodes</h2>
        <p>Nodes in the node tree have a familial relationship, where each node acts as a parent, child, and sibling of other nodes. This relationship is expressed using the form
        </p>
        <code><em>node</em>.<em>relationship</em></code>
        <p>where <code><em>node</em></code> is a currently selected node or object and <code><em>relationship</em></code> is the relationship of another node to the current node. For example, the expression
        </p>
        <code><em>node</em>.parentNode</code>
        <p>refers to the parent of <code><em>node</em></code>. In an HTML document the parent of the <code>body</code> node is the <code>html</code> node, and the parent of the
          <code>html</code> node is the <code>document</code> node, which represents the entire document. The table below describes the other familial relationships under the document object model.
        </p>
        <table id="t1">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Expression</th>
              <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><code><em>node</em>.firstChild</code></td>
              <td>The first child of <code><em>node</em></code>.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><code><em>node</em>.lastChild</code></td>
              <td>The last child of <code><em>node</em></code>.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><code><em>node</em>.childNodes</code></td>
              <td>A collection of all of the nodes contained within <code><em>node</em></code>.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><code><em>node</em>.previousSibling</code></td>
              <td>The sibling prior to <code><em>node</em></code>.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><code><em>node</em>.nextSibling</code</td>
                     <td>The sibling after <code><em>node</em></code>.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><code><em>node</em>.ownerDocument</code></td>
              <td>The root node of the document</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><code><em>node</em>.parentNode</code></td>
              <td>The parent of <code><em>node</em></code>.</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <h2>Node Types, Names, and Values</h2>
        <p>JavaScript provides the following properties to determine each node's type, name, and value:
        </p>
        <code>
               <em>node</em>.nodeType<br />
               <em>node.</em>nodeName<br />
               <em>node.</em>nodeValue<br />
            </code>
        <p>The <code><em>nodeType</em></code> property returns an integer indicating whether the node refers to an element, a text string, a comment, an attribute, and so on. The
          <code><em>nodeName property</em></code> returns the name of the node within the document. Finally, the
          <code><em>nodeValue</em></code> property returns the node's value.
        </p>
      </article>
    </section>

    <footer>
      JSWorks &copy; 2018 (US)
      <span>
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <a href="#">Terms</a>
            <a href="#">Help</a>
         </span>
    </footer>

  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What page are you testing it on? What counts were you expecting on this page and what did you actually see? Where are `isWhiteSpaceNode` and `makeBranches` defined? Please share a [mcve]. Thanks. BTW, `else if (isWhiteSpaceNode(textString) == false) {` can just be `else`. Never use `==` due to confusing type coercions. `if (foo === true)` can usually be clearer as `if (foo)`.

Comment: Thank you! I added the reproducible example.

Comment: Your function is currect, but there has a typo in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<td><code><em>node</em>.nextSibling</code</td>
```

code tag here forget to close

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you so much! This was a school assignment in Cengage and I didn't even write the HTML. I was looking at my own code for the error.